# Como ordeno post uno alado del otro sistema de noticias php

Tags: php, bootstrap, post

Hola que tal estoy dandole diseño a un sistema de noticias pero cuando quiero alinear uno alado del otro solo achica las columnas y siguen estando uno debajo del otro como puedo solucionarlo para que aparezcan uno alado del otro?

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $posts): ?>

<section class="post">

   <div class="container"> 
<!--Card-->
<div class=" card">

    <!--Card image-->
    <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight">
        <div class="thumb">
            <a href="single.php?id=<?php echo $posts ['id']; ?>">
            <div style="padding: 40px; padding-top: 90px; background-size: cover; background-position: center; width: 100%; height: 400px; background-image: url('img/<?php echo $posts ['thumb']; ?>'); ">
            </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/.Card image-->

    <!--Button-->
    <a href="single.php?id=<?php echo $posts ['id']; ?>" class="btn-floating btn-action"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>

    <!--Card content-->
    <div class="card-block">
        <!--Title-->
        <h2 class=" titulopost h3-responsive card-title"><a href="single.php?id=<?php echo $posts ['id']; ?>"> <?php echo $posts ['titulo']; ?></a></h2><hr>

        <!--Text-->
        <p class="card-text"><?php echo $posts ['estracto']; ?></p>
    </div>
    <!--/.Card content-->

    <!-- Card footer -->
    <div class="card-data">
        <ul>
            <li><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <?php echo $posts ['fecha']; ?></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Card footer -->

</div>
<!--/.Card-->
 </div>

</section>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estás usando alguno de los sabores de bootstrap, presta atención a una cosa: la etiqueta `section` siempre tiene la propiedad `display:block` y la etiqueta `container` siempre tiene un ancho fijo que me parece es de 1100px, (o 1130px, algo asi).

Por ambas razones, es mala idea que *cada post* tenga su propia section y container. Más bien debieses hacer:

```
<section class="post">
   <div class="container"> 
   <?php foreach($posts as $post) { ?>

   <div class="card"> ... </div> 

   <?php endforeach; ?>
   </div>
</section>
```

Y hecho esto, revisar que cada `card` tenga al menos las propiedades CSS

```
display: inline-block;
float: left;
```

Si estás usando el beta de bootstrap 4 también puedes usar

```
display: flex;
```

para asegurarte además que cada card tenga el mismo ancho que los demás.

Answer (score 0):

Para que un bloque no ocupe la línea entera (tenga su anchura y altura), puedes aplicar la siguiente regla:

```
elemento {
    display: inline-block;
}
```